# Show that $\lim f_n(x_n) = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Here is the question I want to solve $(b)$ in it:

> [image]

And here is a trial for the solution:

> [image]

But I did not get the idea for the answer of the first part, could someone explain this idea to me please? Also, I think the solution to the second part is not correct as sin^2 is not equal to 1 in this case. Could someone help me in the solution of this part please?

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Ok sorry about that @MartinR .... I will edit my post in 3 hours ... I was just in a hurry

Comment: Take $x=N+\frac 1  2$ instead of $ x=2N+1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm what about my first question?

Comment: For the first part, use the fact that $f$ is continuous along with the line of reasoning: $$\begin{eqnarray*}\|f_n(x_n)-f(x)\| &\leq & \|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)\|+ \|f(x_n)-f(x)\| \\ &\leq & \sup_{t\in E}\|f_n(t)-f(t)\| + \|f(x_n)-f(x)\|\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps some concrete example can clarify the picture.

Let's suppose that $ x_n \to 10000$.

We try to show that $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_n)=0.$$

Since $ x_n \to 10000$, , $x_n$ will be less than $10001$ for sufficiently large $n$. That is $\exists  N_1 \in \Bbb N$   s.t. $n \gt N_1$ $\Rightarrow  x_n \lt 10001$.

Let's choose $N_2= max(N_1, 10002)$

Then for $n\ge N_2$,

$$x_n \lt 10001$$

and noting that $n\ge N_2 \Rightarrow n \gt 10001$

According to definition of $f_n$ ,
$$f_n(x_n)=0   $$  for $\forall n\ge N_2$

Hence $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_n)=0$$

Comment: Is there a better way of proving this?

Comment: but this is not fullfilled  in our case now $n \geq x \leq n+1$ so that I can use the given definition of $f_n(x).$

Comment: I mean $n \leq x \leq n+1$

Comment: we only have a condition on $x_n$ and not $x.$

Comment: $x_n$ has the important condition that it converges to $x$.

We have to make use of this condition to prove the result.

Indeed if ${x_n}$ is divergent, e.g. $x_n=n+\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$,  then $f_n(x_n)=1$for all $n$. 

We will have

$ lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x_n)=1$